# How to move background image in Android Cocos2d

Tags: android

I am trying to move background image from upward to downward direction on cocos2d so that the fixed character sprite seem to be moving in upward direction.
Can any body tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to have two Sprites of screen size . move the sprite from upside to down and the give the position start of second sprite to the endposition of first sprite, this way you can have continues loop of background images.